# How to access element in a data template of list picker

Tags: windows-phone-8

On clicking select all option list picker check boxes must be selected unable to access the check box  which is present in stack panel .I even tried visual tree, but not getting

page1.xaml

```
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <CheckBox Width="75" BorderThickness="0" Checked="CheckBox_Checked_1"></CheckBox>
        <TextBlock Text="Select All" FontSize="38" Margin="0,13,0,0" Width="138" Foreground="Red"  />
    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Name="lpk1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,-10,0,10">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Width="75" BorderThickness="0" Name="chk1" ></CheckBox>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="34" Margin="0,13,0,0" Width="138" Foreground="Red"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Page1.cs

```
              void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
       {
           try
           {
               allbrands = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AllBrand>(e.Result);
               lpk1.DataContext = allbrands.GetBrands;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
       }

       private void CheckBox_Checked_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {


       }
```

Comment: In your code you don't access it. You can use the name `chk1` and use his members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have it:

```
ListBoxItem lboi = (ListBoxItem)lbo.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
StackPanel stack = lboi.Content as StackPanel;
CheckBox chk = stack.Children[0] as CheckBox;
```

Comment: I want to make check boxes get selected Which are in the list box.I cant get how come above provided code function when i check Check box which is out side the list

Comment: getting null in stack

Comment: You must check that the Layout has been created